# Controller pattern .Net

Tags: .net, controller, design-patterns

I'm looking at a number of examples like
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921074%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx

and they use Controller pattern alot.

I'm just interested to know what the Controller is and when is it best to use it?
In the Stock Trade example it sometimes takes two View Models and interacts between them.

In ASP.Net MVC, the controller seems to get input then returns some Action(based on my limited understanding)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**What the Controller is?**
As name says Controller controls the users' actions.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controller_(computing)

> In computing and especially in computer hardware, controller is a
>   chip, an expansion card, or a stand-alone device (usually called a
>   control unit) that interfaces with a peripheral device.

With a little bit manipulation of the above lines,

In programming world, controller is a method that interfaces with operations of entities/objects.

**When is it best to use it?**
Generally, we build the software/applications in the context of Entities/Objects. We rarely consider the different types of actions even-though users' actions play important role in software usability.

*Do not make controller heavy.* Use it as users' action director.

A controller directs users' actions to a specific type of actions.
(e.g. ReadController directs to actions that does read operations).

[VAR Controller pattern](http://www.karticles.com/aspnet-mvc/VAR-Controller-Pattern.html), written in ASP.NET MVC, is a good example that differentiate different web actions.